# How to use yield in Typescript classes

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I am fresher to Typescript, while learning from the site, I got to know that yield can be used for Asynchronous Iteration using for-await-of. The below is the function in Javascript. Please help me how to use in Typescript classes. When I write the below code, I get the error as **TS1163: A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body.** **I want to write the below code in Typescript class**.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/keep-your-promises-in-typescript-using-async-await-7bdc57041308.

```
function* numbers() {
  let index = 1;
  while(true) {
    yield index;
    index = index + 1;
    if (index > 10) {
      break;
    }
  }
}

function gilad() {
  for (const num of numbers()) {
    console.log(num);
  }
}
gilad();
```

I also tried to write in a Typescript class, but it gives compilation issue.

```
public getValues(): number {
        let index = 1;
        while(true) {
            yield index;
            index = index + 1;
            if (index > 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498688/a-yield-expression-is-only-allowed-in-a-generator-body)

Comment: No, that link does not anser my qn, I have already tried.

Comment: I want to write it in Typescript only.

Comment: And you can't switch to TypeScript 3+, aren't you?

Comment: Currently I am using tsc version 3.8.1.

Comment: Hm, maybe I am missing something. I took your code and it works perfectly fine as pure TypeScript

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to put the token `*` in front of your method:

```
class X {
  public *getValues() { // you can put the return type Generator<number>, but it is ot necessary as ts will infer 
        let index = 1;
        while(true) {
            yield index;
            index = index + 1;
            if (index > 10) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1oAcCuAjEBLY0AVAOYCmALgGpggakQAUAlItAPRvQCeA9htMDAA7dBnLRyAC1LQAThQyyR5LmhkBxUkNKyw5HrIA8QjAFssOgHwAaaFjHRc43DB7jtwehDCyu0SBIwAO64ICCOQgBmOtAoqPGoIBQRACakAB7QALzQAIwA3HEJqEGSoaQM5LJ0LMjF9dy4pCApqRmFDcW4QmmZOd290ADUeR2d8biR0AwDGdCWeQAMtUXjCVjyYADWY2sAvqsJB0dIe0A)

Comment: Nice answer, I checked, it is working fine for me. But I cannot define the datatype of this kind of function. Is it a limitation of Typescript lang?

Comment: What do you mean exactly 'you can't define the data type' `Generator<number>` should work. What issue are you having with it ?

Comment: In typescript, I am suggested to write like this `public functionName(): DataType {}`. In this case, how can I mention datatype of return formed by yield. Your solution is working fine for me, I was interested to know how to mention datatype for return type in this case.